# How do I send "extra" data to a Symfony 3.2.x form using FormBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have the following method in a Symfony 3.2.7 controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em        = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // this is the original entity without modified values
    $entity    = $em->getRepository('QuoteBundle:Quote')->find($request->query->get('id'));

    // the entity passed to the form has the values modified coming from the request    
    $form = $this->createForm(CFProgramLevelQuoteType::class, $entity);
    ...
}
```

And this is the form:

```
class CFProgramLevelQuoteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('CFProgramLevel', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => 'QuoteBundle:CFProgramLevel',
                'choice_label'  => 'description',
                'placeholder'   => 'Please select a program',
            ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

I will use a Query Builder to filter some values from `QuoteBundle:CFProgramLevel` so I need to get the unmodified ID from the `$entity` and send it to the form. This is the solution I have in mind so far:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $em        = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity    = $em->getRepository('QuoteBundle:Quote')->find($request->query->get('id'));
    $entity_id = $entity->getCfProgramLevel()->getcfProgramLevelId();   
    $form = $this->createForm(CFProgramLevelQuoteType::class, $entity);
    ...
}
```

But how I can pass that `entity_id` to the form and used it there? If there is a better way to achieve this I am open to hear ideas. I couldn't find anything helpful in Google so any help is appreciated.

**Update**

Trying the solution provided in the answer below I couldn't get it to work either:

```
// controller
$form = $this->createForm(CFProgramLevelQuoteType::class, $entity, ['entity_id' => $entity_id]);

// form
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    dump($options);
    die();
    ...
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Quote::class, 'entity_id' => null]);
    $resolver->setRequired('entity_id');
}
```

> The option "entity_id" does not exist. Defined options are: "action",
>   "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name",
>   "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name",
>   "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id",
>   "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data",
>   "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message",
>   "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters",
>   "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method",
>   "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required",
>   "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message",
>   "validation_groups".

Comment: Might try Form entity query builder in this case: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

Comment: @AndrewNolan I don't have a clue in how this would help here ....

Comment: So you want to take the original `getcfProgramLevelId` before the update and have a selection field with filtered results from the database based on `getcfProgramLevelId` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom options for form type like described on http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#defining-the-field-type

```
class CFProgramLevelQuoteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //$options['entity_id'] contains your id
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('entity_id');
    }
}
```

Pass entity_id:

```
$form = $this->createForm(CFProgramLevelQuoteType::class, $entity, [
    'entity_id' => $entity_id
]);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me `The option "entity_id" does not exist. Defined options are ...`

Comment: Your method setDefaultOptions not even called because it was deprecated since symfony 2.7. You must use configureOptions method. Please check code carefully 
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#deprecated-setdefaultoptions-in-favor-of-configureoptions

Answer (score 1):

This is fully working example (very similar to @striker also). Please check carefully if you haven't got any misspellings. Otherwise try `php bin/console cache:clear`

controller action:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, null, [
        'option1' => 6
    ]);
    return $this->render('default/test.html.twig',[
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

`TestType.php`:

```
class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('test', IntegerType::class, [
            'data' => $options['option1']
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('option1');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_test';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass extra data to a form you can use [OptionsResolver::setDefined](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html#options-without-default-values).

```
// App\Form\SomeFormType
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefined('foo');
}
```

You can pass data in the Controller like this:

```
// Controller
$this->createForm(SomeFormType::class, $entity, ['foo' => $data]);
```

To use the passed data just access the defined key:

```
// App\Form\SomeFormType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    // $options['foo']
}
```